# Member list limit in /etc/group file

Tags: linux, busybox, passwd

I'm creating user with group in my busybox Linux machine

```
addgroup group1
adduser user1 -G group1
```

after creating 20 users I'm getting error like "adduser: unknown group group1",

```
cat /etc/group
group1:x:1002:user1,user2,user3,user4,user5,user6,user7,user8,user9,user10,user11,user12,user13,user14,user15,user16,user17,user18,user19,user20
```

So is there any limit of adding member list in /etc/group?

Comment: for the record there is a hardcoded limit in busybox "libpwdgrp/pwd_grp.c" So you could patch busybox or uclib (it depends on your system) to extend the line buffer length the issue has been reported here http://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/733

Answer (score 0):

Which Linux distribution do you actually use ? `adduser` has a different syntax at least in Ubuntu/Debian by the way I've just made group with 200 user without problem

`` for i in `seq 1 100`; do echo adduser -G group1 "user$i"|| break ; done ``

So it seems to me problem is in another place.

Comment: I'm using busybox's addgroup,adduser

Comment: It is definitely a busybox limitation. I've got the same result with my openwrt box.

Comment: :Are you sure about this behaviour ?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean

Comment: In my case `useradd` doesn't work after 23-th user. However, I've been able to add users into a group manually I've edited /etc/group directly in vi and it works as expected

Comment: Yes exactly,but why busybox's adduser allows only 23 user in /etc/group?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46833/discussion-between-rahul-r-dhobi-and-hostmaster)